# Curl or HTTPRequest

Tags: java, facebook, api, curl

Is it possible to use the facebook API in JAVA using a Java curl library instead of the HTTP classes? A bit confused on the subject, the answer to this will help clarify certain confusions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  I would use the open source Facebook Java SDK as an example of how to do it.  http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-sdk/

But you might save yourself a lot of time and just use the SDK instead of building your own  ;)